# How to get the list of bag options from a journey without recordlocator

Tags: sabre, bag

We need to see if Ryan Air makes available the cabin bag option before booking.
Therefore what is the action verb we can use to get this list with flight information (itinerary, segment) ?

Thanks :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It called "BrandedFares" attribute on the Sabre side. With BrandedFares option enabled, you get 1 basic price with its extra prices (cabin bag, meal, etc.).

If you're using BargainFinderMax operation to search and get flights, you have to set BrandedFareIndicators attribute as true, like this:

```
<TravelerInfoSummary>
<PriceRequestInformation>
    <TPA_Extensions>
        <BrandedFareIndicators MultipleBrandedFares="true"/>
    </TPA_Extensions>
</PriceRequestInformation>
</TravelerInfoSummary>
```

And also, your PCC also have to be available and has access to get BrandedFares, you need to discuss it with your Sabre consultant.

Regards.